# Example to show strong law of large numbers is stronger than weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am aware there are already plenty of answers to this question by reasoning from definition of almost sure convergence versus convergence in probability, so I would like to see an example which satisfies WLLN but not SLLN (I am kind of a learn-by-example learner).

Comment: Which version of the theorems do you think of? They tend to have the same assumptions, so there will be no example where they differ.

Comment: I am not sure which version (I don't even know there are more than one version of WLLN/SLLN). I assume there are some examples for which they behave differently because I assume when we have a strong and weak version of some property/law, the strong one usually needs more assumptions to hold. One example would be Lagrangian duality.

Comment: I illustrated an example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205564/2958 taking an [example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law) where there was no expectation in a Lebesgue integration sense but was in a Dirichlet integral sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $X_k$ are i.i.d. variables with density
$$f(x)=\frac{c}{(1+x^2) \log(2+x^2)} $$
on $\mathbb R$, where $c$ is chosen to ensure that $\int_{ \mathbb R} f(x)\,dx=1$. Then $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ satisfy $S_n/n \to 0$ in probability, but $ S_n/n$ does not converge almost surely.
This can be inferred from the criteria in [1].

The sharp condition for the WLLN is given in Theorem 1, Section VII.7, page 235 of [1], while the sharp condition for the SLLN is integrability of $|X_k|$, see the discussion in [1] page 236 and Theorem 4 in Section VII.8 there.

[1] Feller, William. An introduction to probability theory and its applications, vol 2. John Wiley & Sons, 1971.